# Bootstrap4 Flexboxes how to use the predefined width for different sizes

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am new to bootstrap4 and now using flexboxes to build a layout. In 1 class I use flex-row. The row changes into a column when the size gets to small. within this class I have made 2 other classes with each a width of 50% (class="w-50"). When I reach a certain size I want the 50% to change into a 100%.

I have tried to use w-sm-100 class but this didn`t seem to work.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row">

  <div class="w-50">

  </div>

  <div class="w-50">


  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Columns are there for this purpose

Use .col-sm-6 instead of creating you own custom css
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid

Comment: it is no custom css it are all bootstrap4 classes for flexboxes

Comment: These are utilities classes and they generally don't have media queries applied on them. If you are want to make a two equal size divs and make them full width at certain viewport size then i suggest you to use columns.